# Mongoosejs: using query.or() with geospatial query

Tags: mongoose, geospatial, mongodb-query

I have a query that's supposed to do the following:
Take two sets of coordinates and return the locations that are near any of the coordinates.

I'm working on Node.js with Mongoose.js.

The original query code is below (before I tried using the `query.or()` syntax:

```
query.or([{geoNear: "loc", near: start, spherical: true},{geoNear: "loc", near: end}]);
```

The issue seems to be using the `$or` because I initially tried the code as:

```
            that.count({
                _cat: _cat ,
                $or: [
                    {
                        loc: { $nearSphere: start }
                    },
                    {
                        loc: { $nearSphere: end }
                    }
                ]}, function(err, c) {
                    // do something
                });
```

When I search using one location without the `$or` (i.e. `start` or `end`) I am able to get results. That is how I'm certain that the problem is with the `$or`.

**Does mongoDB/mongoose support using `$or` with geospatial search, or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `$or` does not work, so I have opted for running 2 queries for now, then evaluating the result of each in order to return the count. It works for me because I don't need the actual count, but I need to know if there are any locations available within a certain distance of each point.

If anyone has a similar problem, and use this approach as a work-around, remember to nest the second query in the callback of the first query. This is obviously more problematic when you have more than 2 locations that you're querying.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to do a single geo search with multiple optional locations? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: I honestly can't remember what I ended up doing. I looked at my codebase, and couldn't see a trace of `$or`, so I definitely found a work-around somehow. Mongo 206 now supports using `$or` with geolocation data